# How can I change the vertical position of the y-axis with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Other questions hinted towards using margins, but this does not work for me.

Here's a minimal working example, making a large margin to the right works:

```
library(ggplot2)


df <- diamonds[1:100,]

p <- ggplot(df, aes(table, depth)) + geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=20, margin=unit(c(0.1, 10.1, 0.1, 0.1), unit="cm")))
print(p)
```

[image: Image1]

but making a large one to the top or bottom doesn't:

```
library(ggplot2)


df <- diamonds[1:100,]

p <- ggplot(df, aes(table, depth)) + geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=20, margin=unit(c(10.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), unit="cm")))
print(p)
```

[image: Image2]

Comment: this is a really dumb hacky solution and I'm sorry. But I just tried it by adding a lot of empty space in the axis title (as in: " [lots of space bar here that doesn't show on stackoverflow]           axis title") and got results. Then I think you can just use scale_y_continuous(vjust = whatever) to make any formatting adjustments.

Comment: What's the output you want exactly, to change the alignment of the axis title? That would be by setting hjust. AFAIK the title is created as a block that spans the height of the plotting area, so setting the margin at the top or bottom shouldn't change anything

Comment: "How can I change the vertical position of the y-axis" --> What do you want to change it to?

Comment: I want to move the y-axis title to the top and misalign it so much that there is additional whitespace between the actual plot and the upper end of the figure